# Boot Camp Audio Issue

Tags: audio, bootcamp, driver

I'm using Boot Camp on my Mac and the audio seems incredibly bad. According to what I can find in settings, it is 16-bit. Usually there are more options than this. I've heard online that this is Apple's fault for including bad drivers, but I am wondering if there is a way around it or some third-party drivers that I can install. I've tried re downloading the drivers and looking through all of the settings. There is an enhance option which only seems to make the sound louder which then makes it sound worse. I've looked through 12 pages of Google searches and I can't find any fixes. Any help, ideas or suggestions are appreciated.[image]

Comment: Which version of Windows? What is the model/year of your Mac? Which version of macOS are you using? Did you use the Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows or did you use some other method to install? Was this a new install or an upgrade from a pervious version of Windows?  Did you modify the Boot Camp Assistant application in any way? Did you use the Boot Camp Assistant to download the drivers or did you download a different way? Did you use the Boot Camp Installer or did you install the drivers by some other method?

Comment: "Which version of Windows?" I installed the latest ISO file a few days ago. I completed all updates in Windows Update and Apple Software Update. All drivers were also installed successfully after I installed the OS. "What is the model/year of your Mac?" 2019 MacBook Pro 13". "Did you use the Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows?" Yes. "Was this a new install?" Yes. "Did you modify the Boot Camp Assistant application in any way?" No. "Did you use the Boot Camp Assistant to download the drivers?" Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with 16 bit and 48000 Hz output, that's actually a bit better than CD quality and +100% as much as your ear can hear anyway. The audio drivers Apple provides are more or less alright as well (refer to P.S. if you need details).

The problem is macOS has built-in system-wide equalization of sound and Windows does not (also no sound enhancements are built-in to driver). So use Dolby Atmos app to crank up lows and lower highs or simply go for [this Equalizer APO preset](https://github.com/naozumi520/mbp16-bootcamp-speakers-mod) (it will override Dolby Atmos if you have it). Don't forget to check Use audio enhancement tickbox in your screenshot if you'll use any system-wide equalizer.

P.S. In case you'll hear random pop sound during media playback while using any equalizer (Dolby Atmos, Equalizer APO, etc.) - that's a [known issue](https://www.macrumors.com/2019/12/06/apple-plans-fix-16-inch-macbook-pro-popping-sound/), no fix so far both for Windows and macOS. However I developed a workaround for the stop/pause pop sound in Windows [using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74129840/).

Comment: You should hear how tinny it is. No base at all. If CD quality sounds like that, then there's no wonder I don't listen to them.

Comment: Equalizer APO preset linked above will get your bass back in no time. I'm using it myself with 2019 16-inch MBP and 2012 15-inch rMBP. CD quality has nothing to do with the amount of bass computer outputs. It's APO ([Audio Processing Object](https://github.com/dechamps/APO)) that does the trick using equalization (it adds "volume" to the music). Apple tweaks macOS's APO (built-in system-wide equalizer) but doesn't care about Windows APO. But you can easily get it close enough to macOS with a open source APO that supports parametric equalization (i.e. Equalizer APO) and self-tweaking or preset.